Taking admission in the Ph.D. program of Electrical Engineering in USA universities without supervisor consent, what are chances of getting funding?
I am Electrical Engineering student who holds Master's degree and starting to apply for Ph.D. admission in USA universities this year. I have heard that for Ph.D program in USA , you don't have to take supervisor or professor consent to apply for program. The university websites also writes about the admitted Ph.D student will receive funding and financial aid in the form of assistantship etc.
My concern is that is it okay to apply without contacting supervisor or faculty member in advance, and later a student can choose their respective supervisor during their studies?
I need suggestions and advice from senior students or researchers who have experience in Graduate Schools and especially regarding applying to Graduate School without supervisor consent? What are your take if I also apply in this way?
Thank you

Yes, this is completely normal, you apply to the department and find an advisor after you’re in. See the first canonical question linked above. Some people do contact professors anyway, and in some rare cases it can help, but in your case, it is probably best not to. See the other linked questions for more discussion of this.

So , you mean I should not submit admission without professors approval?

That's the opposite of what I said. But don't take my word for it; read the linked questions.

Okay. I contacted graduate admission and they emphasize on linking with professor because at the end it is the professor who has authority to hire you as GRA .

That is generally unusual for the US. But obviously you should follow the instructions of the graduate school you are interested in attending, so I'm glad you found out.
